# Stanford Named Entity Recognition tagging breaks when there is a full stop in the text?

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am recently working in a project which involves Named entity recognition. 
I am generating the NER model by providing my own training data. 
The problem with NER is that it stops tagging once it encounters with a full stop.
For example if I have text like

> "John works in India. He works at Intel Inc. "

the NER tagger will give the following output for the above text

> "John-NAME" "works-O" "in-O" "India-PLACE".

It does not process the successive sentence

> i.e "He works in Intel Inc."

So basically it breaks at full stop(.).

Is there any way I could change this in NER?
Can this problem be solved in the property file?

The data looks like:

> "1.John eats a banana 2. he goes to office 3.he is the captain of the team 5.HE LIKES CRICKET 6. HE GOES SWIMMING 7.he likes apple"

So in this case i cannot use `sentence tokenizer` as it splits the sentence based on the periods(full stop).

And in relation to the original question about `NER`, the tagging breaks on the first occurence of a period(full stop).

The sentence tokenizer tokenizes the above given text as given in the code

```
    text = "1.John eats a banana 2. he goes to office 3.he is the captain of the team 5.HE LIKES CRICKET 6. HE GOES SWIMMING 7.he likes apple"
    sents = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
```

> The output looks like: ['1.John eats a banana 2. he goes to office 3.he is the captain of the team 5.HE LIKES CRICKET 6.','HE GOES SWIMMING 7.he likes apple']

Since there are no proper periods in the text the sentence tokenizer cannot extract exact sentences.

Now i want to give the whole chunk of the text to the NER. I have given training data which looks like:

```
    This is just a part of entire data
    1   O
    .   O
    John    PER
    eats    O
    a   O
    banana  O
    2   O
    .   O
    he  PER
    goes    O
    to  O
    office  O
    3   O
    .   O
    he  PER
    is  O
    the O
    captain O
    of  O
    the O
    team    O
    5   O
    .   O
    HE  PER
    LIKES   O
    CRICKET O
```

Now the code for NER is like this:

```
    from nltk.tag.stanford import NERTagger
    import os
    java_path = "/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java.exe"
    os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
    st = NERTagger('../ner-model.ser.gz','../stanford-ner.jar')
    tagging = st.tag(text.split())
```

From the above code the tagging is done only till the occurence of first period(full stop).

Comment: If the sentence tokenizer segments at periods and your NE recognizer stops at the first period, what exactly is the problem? If you need to recognize NEs that contain periods (e.g., abbreviations), the problem is squarely with your recognizer-- which you tell us nothing about.

Comment: Please provide some code that shows briefly what you have tried so far.  We don't want to spend time guessing

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp Can you help with my problem??

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by tagging one sentence at a time:

```
sents = nltk.sent_tokenize(alltext)
for sentence in sents:
    # tokenize into words, apply NE recognizer
```

Comment: what you said can be done. But the textual data which I have is not well formatted. It contains data like "1. john eats icecream 2.he eats burgers etc". I forgot to mention in the question the problem with my data. So here sentence tokenization won't work.

Comment: Have you tried it? Sentence tokenizers don't just look for periods.

Comment: Retrain a punkt sent tokenizer and that might work. There's no easy way out for non-clean realistic data .

Comment: First check that the regular sentence tokenizer doesn't work. Don't just assume, and don't let one error dissuade you: What performance are you looking for? (The Punkt tokenizer is about 99% accurate on normal English text.)

Comment: Using sentence tokenizer does not work because the sentences are not getting tokenized.
It searches for a period(full stop) and then splits the sentence.

Comment: What is "it"? That's not the only thing the sentence tokenizer does.  And if the sentence tokenizer can't tell a sentence ends at a certain point, how does the NE recognizer stumble there? Something is not right in your description.

Comment: In fact I think you need to edit your question and add **a lot** more information: You're asking for help with a NE recognizer you don't identify, which has trouble with input you don't show. What do you expect anyone here to do? Start by pasting in a chunk of *real* input data with about 10 sentences, and explain what the problem is.

Comment: @alexis I have described the data I am dealing with.
I just wanted to know whether there is a way by which i could avoid the stopping of NER tagging on occurence of a period(full stop).